# OnStartCommand in service crashes list elements

Tags: java, android, service

As in title I have very strange problem with bound service.

To be sure my service works in 2 ways. It's launched by cyclic AlarmBroadcast (by `startService`) for downloading data and it could be binded with clients.
Service download data to local database and when some specific client is connected while download (will use this data) service get it and send REFRESH flag to client which apply changes from database.

```
public class MsgService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG_MSG = "MSG_SERVICE";
    private final Context context = this;
    private List<Message> clients;
    private Messenger messenger = new Messenger(new IncomingHandler(this));

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.v(LOG_MSG, "Message service started");
        new AsyncMsgsDownloadManager(this).execute();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return messenger.getBinder();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.v(LOG_MSG, "Message service created");
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
                Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        thread.start();
        exceptionHandler = new ExceptionHandler();
        clients = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Message>());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.v(LOG_MSG, "Message service destroyed");
    }

    private void sendResponseToClients() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //update local database
            }
        });
        t.join();
        for(Message client : clients) {
            if ("TasksPerson".equals(client.obj)) {
                client.replyTo.send(Message.obtain(null, MSG.REFRESH_TASKS.ordinal()));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    static class IncomingHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<MsgService> _service;

        IncomingHandler(MsgService msgService) {
            _service = new WeakReference<>(msgService);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (MSG.getEnum(msg.what)) {
                case REGISTER_CLIENT: {
                    _service.get().clients.add(msg);
                    break;
                }
                case UNREGISTER_CLIENT: {
                    _service.get().clients.remove(msg);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    static class AsyncMsgsDownloadManager extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final WeakReference<MsgService> service;

        AsyncMsgsDownloadManager(MsgService service) {
            this.service = new WeakReference<>(service);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //downloading data from server
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            try {
                service.get().stopSelf();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                //Service already closed?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, that everything is okay when I just bind client messanger to my service - it appears in clients-list and I can simply send messages via clients messengers. But when some client is connected and service get `onStartCommand` list crashes.

List still have reference to object (I checked it, its the same number in android studio), but this object if full of just null or zero arguments.

Comment: Okay, when I back to code today, I thought a little about Messages in android.os. I think it's the only thing in my code which not work as I thought.

I'm not sure, but I it possible, that system clear messages after receiving (I mean clear all fields) without looking for reference? I read something about `Message.obtain()` method (I also use it) which reuse recycled messages, so maybe it's a problem.